# How to open GridDetail for GridElement in Vaadin Testcase?

Tags: java, selenium, vaadin, vaadin14

I have a simple `VaadinGrid` that opens a detail if you click the row in the UI (like [here](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-grid/java-examples/item-details)). I use Vaadin 14.0.12.

Unfortunately I am no table to 'click' and open the details in my testcase. If I click the row by myself the detail is shown. If I execute a click in my testcase on a row it isn't shown. Any idea why?

Adding the details to the Grid:

```
    grid.setItemDetailsRenderer(new ComponentRenderer<Component, Item>(item -> {
        return new TestGridDetail(item); // contains some text only
    }));
```

**Testbench-Testcase:**

I use the current version of geckodriver (Firefox) to execute the tests. The Grid is not empty and contains rows.

Finding the Grid (works fine):

```
var gridElement = $(TestGridElement.class).waitForFirst();
```

I tried to open the detail with:

```
gridElement.getRow(0).getDetails().click();
gridElement.getRow(0).click();
```

The details do not open in the UI though.

The [official documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/flow/components/tutorial-flow-grid.html) mentions a method to open it but `GridElement` does not offer this one.

> You can show and hide item details programmatically using the
>   setDetailsVisible() method,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to execute a `click` on a `Cell`, not on a `Row`.

```
gridElement.getCell(0, 0).click();
```

The command opens the details of the Grid's first row.